# How to boot to cloned drive (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, grub, multi-boot, bootloader

I have cloned my system drive to another partition, but it doesn't show in the boot menu (the one that comes with Windows 8 where I can select OS to boot).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Use EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

EasyBCD can easily detect the partition and add an entry in the boot menu. If it does not work, try to *mark the partition* as active in the Disk Management (search in start screen).

### [Use GRUB](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)

You can boot using the Boot-Repair Disc, which comes with Boot-Repair pre-installed. You can use gparted to mark the partition as active/bootable as well.

More instructions can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_:_get_a_CD_including_Boot-Repair)

Comment: EasyBCD was easy.  I had assumed I would have to burn a CD and boot from it, but I just needed to launch it as a Windows program, and could easily edit the boot information.